# how to turn off the break word in css?

Tags: html, css

how do I turn off the broken word in CSS? If the word contains the keyboard hyphenation, not the soft hyphen.

For example: 
One day talking to my first-year roommate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **white-space: nowrap**

```
p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you want use nowrap on only part of a text, you can simply put that text in a *span* element and then apply nowrap to it.

Another much simpler way to prevent just your hyphenated string from wrapping is to replace the keyboard hyphen with `&#8209;`. This will render it as a non-breaking hyphen.

[Updated example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zo2uat1s/3/)

[css](/questions/tagged/css)[css3](/questions/tagged/css3)[html](/questions/tagged/html)

Comment: while I am using the white space property in CSS, while I create the table the hyphened word will overwrite the table specified width.

Comment: I need to avoid the word break and soft hyphen in the specified width even though it contain the keyboard hyphen.

Comment: Make sure the div containing your text has position set to relative, as well as a specified width.

Comment: I've included an example on jsFiddle so you can see

Comment: thank you so much. If I need to do the word break at the same time keyboard hyphenated words do not break in the specified width, how to solve on this.

Comment: Won't this prevent any wrapping whatsoever, including on spaces?

Comment: Not a problem. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you the issue solved.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

```
// Don't force hyphenate
p { word-wrap: normal; }

// Force words to hyphenate
p { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I don't think the OP is talking about forcing or not forcing; he is talking about allowing or not allowing.